# How to make this transform with React-Native?

Tags: react-native, transform

i try to use style.transform attribute
but i can't make the transform, there is not so many doc , crying ...

[image]

here is the css3 code:

> transform: translateZ(-100px) translateX(-24%) translateY(0)
>   rotateY(60deg);

Comment: I got it my self，see https://snack.expo.io/HJYvJKI3l

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Here is a pretty close result:

[image]

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.child} />
    </View>
  )
},

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      backgroundColor:'green',
      flex: 1,
  },
  child: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    transform: [
      { perspective: 850 },
      { translateX: - Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.24 },
      { rotateY: '60deg'},

    ],
  }
});
```

See full example: https://rnplay.org/apps/Qg7Bhg

Comment: @alucard.g rpplay is no longer available, can you provide alternate to this?

Comment: Hi, I applied the transform to the Image. How to save the transformed image without using the third-party modules in React-native