# how to make this animate with react-native?

Tags: animation, react-native, transform

[image]
[How to make this transform with React-Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538303/how-to-make-this-transform-with-react-native)

i want this static position

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            loaded:false,

            transform:[{ perspective: 0 },
                      { translateX: width },
                      { rotateY: '0deg'}],
            isMenuOpen:false,
        }
    }
```

animate to this position

```
Animated.timing(
                this.state.transform,
                {toValue:[{ perspective: 850 },
                          { translateX: -width * 0.24 },
                          { rotateY: '60deg'}]},
            ).start();
```

how to write the animation code ？

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Animated in such way... Look at [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#content) link you need to do next thing:

```
<MyComponent style={{
          transform:[{ perspective: this.state.anim.interpolate({
                                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                                    outputRange: [0, 850],
                    })},
                     { translateX: this.state.anim.interpolate({
                                     inputRange: [0, 1],
                                     outputRange: [width, -width * 0.24],
                    })},
                     { rotateY: this.state.anim.interpolate({
                                     inputRange: [0, 1],
                                     outputRange: ["0deg", "60deg"],
                    })}],
       }],
     }}/>
```

------////------

```
            Animated.timing(this.state.anim, {
              toValue: 1
            }),
```

------////--------

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            anim: AnimateValue(0)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the right direction but you can simplify this by reusing just 1 Animated.Value (assuming you want the same kind of timing animation on the 3 transforms).

Comment: @simcha there is an error , how can fix it ? thank you !Transform with key of "perspective" cannot be zero: {"perspective":0}

https://rnplay.org/apps/pBrrUg

Comment: @JeanRegisser ,Can you help me solve the problem ? here，https://rnplay.org/apps/pBrrUg , thank you so much !

Comment: I solved it ! thank you all ! @JeanRegisser,@Simcha . 
https://rnplay.org/apps/pBrrUg