# How to get a simple right slide animation working with React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm having trouble with animations in React Native. I've been able to get a few things working but they're all very similar to the tutorials and I can't get them to apply to my own stuff.

To get me going in the right direction.. **How can I animate this movement from left to right?**

**Desired outcome**

When clicking on 'Slide Right' button the main container (MainPosition) smoothly moves left (marginLeft -screenWidth) to reveal the 'pane' (paneDimensions) to the right (Right Pane)

(The below code works as intended but without the sliding animation effect)

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Animated, Easing, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import styles from './AppStyleSheet'

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    let screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width,
        screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
    this.state = {
      MainPosition: [styles.main, {width: screenWidth * 2}, {height: screenHeight}, {marginTop: 0}, {marginLeft: 0}],
      paneDimensions: [styles.pane, {width: screenWidth}, {height: screenHeight}]
    }
  }
  SlidePane =(direction)=> {
    let screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height,
        screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width,
        theTopMargin,
        theLeftMargin;
    if (direction === 'right') {
      theLeftMargin = parseInt('-' + screenWidth)
    }
    this.setState({
      MainPosition: [styles.main, {width: screenWidth * 2}, {height: screenHeight}, {marginTop: 0}, {marginLeft: theLeftMargin}]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={this.state.MainPosition}>
          <StatusBar hidden />
          <View style={this.state.paneDimensions}>
            <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.SlidePane('right')}>
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Slide Right</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={this.state.paneDimensions}>
            <Text style={styles.paneText}>Right Pane</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

    ); // end return
  } // end render
} // end export
```

**AppStyleSheet.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    "main": {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      backgroundColor: 'hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1)',
    },
    "row": {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
    },
    "pane": {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      borderTopWidth: 50,
      borderTopColor: 'transparent',
      backgroundColor: 'hsla(38, 100%, 73%, 1)',
    },
    "paneText": {
      fontSize: 20,
      color: 'black'
    },
    "buttonsContainer": {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      paddingTop: 0,
      paddingBottom: 3,
    },
    "button": {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      width: '94%',
      marginBottom: 3,
      padding: 10,
      backgroundColor: 'hsla(38, 100%, 50%, 1)'
    },
    "buttonText": {
      fontSize: 20,
      color: '#FFF'
    },
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to work through a similar problem right now, except I need to slide my view in from the bottom right after it's rendered. So I was trying to animate the marginTop value instead of marginLeft like you did. Confused how you got this to work since I'm getting an error "style property 'marginTop' is not supported by native animation module". I've seen a lot of people online say that this valid and the only way to achieve this is to animate translateY instead. It's been a while since you posted this, but if you could offer some insight I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @MichaelK.Thai Hi Michael, I haven't been working with react native lately but translateY should be the better, smoother way to go. (animating position or margin, as I did here, can be very clunky on underpowered, mobile devices and tablets) In my example you could try `transform: [{translateY: Math.abs(screenHeight)}],` [check this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37540016/3377049) to see how transform properties are written in an array. Apologies, I don't have any react native stuff fired up to test it now but let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this working (I'm not sure it's the right way and I'm sure it's not the best way but it's the only way I know how at this moment)

It's based on the second example in this [React Native animations tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_animations.htm) from Tutorials Point (which is so far the easiest for me to follow of the RN tutorials out there)

**APP.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Animated, Easing, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import styles from './AppStyleSheet'

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    let screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width,
        screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
    this.state = {
      MainPosition: [styles.main, {width: screenWidth * 2}, {height: screenHeight}, {marginTop: 0}, {marginLeft: 0}],
      paneDimensions: [styles.pane, {width: screenWidth}, {height: screenHeight}]
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.animatedLeftMargin = new Animated.Value(0)
  }
  SlidePane =(direction)=> {
    let screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height,
        screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width,
        theLeftMargin;
    if (direction === 'right') {
      theLeftMargin = parseInt('-' + screenWidth);
      Animated.timing(this.animatedLeftMargin, {
        toValue: theLeftMargin,
        duration: 300
      }).start()
    }
    this.setState({
      MainPosition: [styles.main, {width: screenWidth * 2}, {height: screenHeight}, {marginTop: 0}]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Animated.View style={[this.state.MainPosition, {marginLeft: this.animatedLeftMargin}]}>
          <StatusBar hidden />
          <View style={this.state.paneDimensions}>
            <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.SlidePane('right')}>
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Slide Right</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={this.state.paneDimensions}>
            <Text style={styles.paneText}>Right Pane</Text>
          </View>
        </Animated.View>
    ); // end return
  } // end render
} // end export
```

**P.S.**

If anybody wants to know more about how I did it, reply to this and I'll hopefully have a better understanding by then to be able to update this answer with an explanation.